# Match a corresponding Table entry when a value lies between two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to build a summary sheet based on a table, which I can then use for `Index` and `Match`.

I'm using the following formula `=INDEX(ISO[ISO],MATCH(ROW(A1),ISO[RowTally],1))` to try and create a number of rows from the `[@RowTally]` column and populate with the corresponding entry from `[@ISO]` i.e. `rows` *1-3157* would contain **ISO4762**, `rows` *3158-4129* would contain **ISO7380**, etc. But only getting `#N/A` as the output from my formula

The table looks like this

[image: ISO Table]

Comment: The problem should hail from your definition of the search value for the MATCH function: ROW(A1) isn't a valid cell reference. Using structured language you can define a single cell only as an intersection. That is complicated. But you can use normal sheet referencing, and you might be able to calculate the sheet address of a cell and then use INDIRECT/ADDRESS to get the cell's value.

Comment: I'm trying to match the value of the ```row``` to the value in the table. So ```row``` number 1 < 3157, so ISO4762. I've also tried populating a ```column``` with ascending numbers and trying to reference that in the ```match```, but I get the same error.

Comment: MATCH requires a single value, like "5311". `ROW(A1)` always returns "1". Since that doesn't exist in `ISO[RowTally]` the return is *#N/A*

Comment: Thanks @Variatus. I think you were two steps ahead of where I was thinking and I missed the point. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after breaking out the formula and data from the table. When using `Match(#Ref,#Lookup,1)` if the smallest value is larger than #ref it fails, if you give it a clause or include a 0 at the start of the list, it works fine.